# PowerShell cmdlets for Azure AD federated domain (No ADFS)

Tags: azure, powershell, subdomain, powershell-cmdlet, federated

I have domain1 and domain2 added in Azure AD. Trying to federate the 1st domain able to federate while 2nd causing problem, Gives the following problem:

```
Convert-MsolDomaintoFederated -DomainName <domain2> -SupportMultipleDomain
```

> Convert-MsolDomaintoFederated : Failed to connect to Active Directory
>   Federation Services 2.0 on the local machine.  Please try running
>   Set-MsolADFSContext before running this command again. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Convert-MsolDomaintoFederated -DomainName cloud-office.co -SupportMultipleDomain
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Convert-MsolDomainToFederated], FederationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCommandSequenceGeneva,Microsoft.Online.Identity.Federation.Powershell.ConvertDomainToFederated

=============================================================================

Here, we don't have on prim AD and having two domains wants to federate. No ADFS

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following, as appropriate for your situation:

1. If AD FS is still running, use the `Set-MsolADFSContext` cmdlet to specify the server on which AD FS is running.

for example: `Set-MsolADFSContext –Computer <ServerName>`

For more information about the `Set-MsolADFSContext` cmdlet, see `[Set-MsolADFSContext][1]`.

2. If AD FS is not running, use the `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication` cmdlet to change the domain to a managed domain.

for example:

```
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName <DomainName> -Authentication Managed
```

For more info about the `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication` cmdlet, see `[Set-MsolDomainAuthentication][1]`.

Hope it helps.